# The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty - Even when SECRET_KEY is set in settings.py

Tags: python, django

I keep getting this error when i try to import my models.py file into views.py or any of the other python script in my App directory,

I have the SECRET_KEY in settings.py and also add app in the list of INSTALLED_APPS,

wsgi.py contains

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')  # I replaced my project name
```

manage.py also contains

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projectname.settings')
```

I have checked through other people's installations in StackOverflow posts. My code works but importing models just break it

I use this command to import my class

```
from app_name.models import subscribers
```

and subscribers is defined thus

```
  class subscribers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=120)
    email = models.CharField('Email', max_length=120)
    access_token = models.TextField()
    expires_in = models.DateTimeField('token expiry date')
```

I have already executed makemigrations and migrate commands but being a newbie I don't know where else to look. Please save a soul it's been 3 days

thanks.

---

below is my settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for ps project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from oauth_outlook.views import gettoken

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY='l!u#h@an5lj%b))=fzhv6r-3ay1&29=ls0*o1_^dxi(01x$et@'
#SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", "l!u#h@an5lj%b))=fzhv6r-3ay1&29=ls0*o1_^dxi(01x$et@")
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'oauth_outlook',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'lockdown.middleware.LockdownMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ps.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ps.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
LOCKDOWN_PASSWORDS = ('letmein', 'beta')

LOCKDOWN_VIEW_EXCEPTIONS = [
    gettoken,
]
```

Comment: can you post the settings.py file code also

Comment: Looks like your `settings.py` is configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the following import is causing the problem:

```
from oauth_outlook.views import gettoken
```

Importing views or models in the settings can cause circular imports and lead to the SECRET_KEY error message even when it is set. I don’t like the way django-lockout is encouraging you to import views for the `LOCKDOWN_VIEW_EXCEPTIONS` setting.

I suggest you set [`LOCKDOWN_URL_EXCEPTIONS`](https://github.com/Dunedan/django-lockdown/blob/master/README.rst#lockdown_url_exceptions) instead, then the import isn’t required.

```
LOCKDOWN_URL_EXCEPTIONS = (
    r'^gettoken$',   # replace with gettoken view
)
```